# Trying to import data from Excel sheet into SQL Server table with different datatypes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am try to import data from an Excel sheet into a SQL Server table. I have one column with data type decimal.

I get an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

This is my code

```
Price = Convert.ToDecimal(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 13]).Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by myself thank you all for your kind response and your kind support. here is my solution

```
   string pricevalue = ((Excel.Range) range.Cells[row, 14]).Text;
   cards.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(pricevalue);
```